# Embed sqlite database to docker container?

Tags: docker

I'm new to [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). Is it possible to embed a sqlite database in a docker container and have it updated every time my script in that container runs?

Comment: Can you post your dockerfile and entrypoint script? If you haven't got this far, what's the objective/purpose of tracking each time the container runs how does this relate to the what container does? What behaviour do you expect when several people run the same image?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Dockerfile example to install sqlite3

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN sudo apt-get -y update
RUN sudo apt-get -y upgrade
RUN sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
RUN mkdir /db
RUN /usr/bin/sqlite3 /db/test.db
CMD /bin/bash
```

persist the db file inside host OS folder /home/dbfolder

```
docker run -it -v /home/dbfolder/:/db imagename
```

Comment: Just a note - using a volume to persist your data is going to have potentially heavy performance costs.

Comment: a built-in example:  mediawiki official container

Comment: @Chris is there a more performant way to persist data in a container?

Comment: May I ask why this line? `RUN /usr/bin/sqlite3 /db/test.db` Thanks

Comment: I think that line actually creates the database file called `test.db` @Bill

Answer (score 19):

If you want to persist the data in sqlite, use host directory/file as a data volume
Refer "Mount a host directory as a data volume" section in
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Hi @sramu can you please explain about how to install sqlite in docker container? and point the location of data volume to it?