# Cannot initiate RabbitMQ when dockerize my Flask - Celery - RabbitMQ application

Tags: docker, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I am new in Docker and I want to dockerize my Flask-Celery-RabbitMQ app which connects to a sqlite database.

This is my tree files:

```
--dockerized_app
--celery_app
    --app
         --__init__.py
         --routes.py
         --modules.py
         --celery_endpoints.py
    run.py
    config.py
Dockerfile
requirements.txt
docker-compose.yml
my_db.db
```

If I want to run this app without Docker I usually do:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin 
rabbitmq-server 

export FLASK_APP=run.py
flask run

celery -A run.celery worker --loglevel=info
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
ADD ./celery_app/ /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT celery -A celery_app worker --loglevel=info
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

    rabbit:
        hostname: rabbit
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
        ports:
            - "5673:5672"

    worker:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        links:
            - rabbit
        depends_on:
            - rabbit
```

requeriments.txt

```
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
SQLAlchemy==1.2.7
celery==4.2.1
```

I run docker-compose build and then I create the image. Celery starts well, but rabbitMQ doesnt and I get this error:

```
[2018-07-25 14:51:12,218: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect 
to amqp://guest:**@XXX.X.X.X:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

I think that the problem is that I am not declaring

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
```

which is necessary to start RabbitMQ, but I dont know how to do it.

Also I dont know if Flask is starting well.

Comment: why not try to use ```./requirements.txt``` inside of your Dockerfile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed sqlite database to docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711818/embed-sqlite-database-to-docker-container)

Comment: Add your database file to docker and change the config.py according to new location of db file.

Comment: The FB file needs to exist in the docker container.  //Users/my_pc_name/Desktop/dockerized_app/my_db.db  does not.  The link in the close comment shows you what you need to do.

Comment: @Laura What is your `broker_url` ?