# Adding volume forces container to exit

Tags: c#, .net, docker, sqlite

I have a .net + React.js application and I am trying to conatinerize it. Currently I am trying to mount sqlite database on my container. Database provider is SQLite so basically I am trying to do what the [Embed sqlite database to docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711818/embed-sqlite-database-to-docker-container) thread suggests. When I am running the following docker-compose.yml file everything is all alright, but database does not work:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
```

but when I add

```
volumes:
    - "./:/app"
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.

Possible reasons for this include:

  * You intended to execute a .NET program:

      The application 'WebApp.dll' does not exist.

  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:

      It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.

      Install a .NET SDK from:

        https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Why does adding a volume cause the container to exit?

Comment: The bind mount over `/app` hides everything from the image in that directory and replaces it with content from the host; if your Dockerfile built the application there, it's not visible any more.  You might consider using an out-of-process database, like PostgreSQL in a separate container, to avoid problems like this.

Comment: The important detail that question doesn't make 100% clear is that the container directory with the SQLite database, that you `volumes:` mount into, needs to be a different directory from the directory with your built application.  Where [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40769465) uses a path `/db`, literally use a path `/db`, separate from the `/app` directory.

Comment: I agree with @DavidMaze. I assume that you're building your application in the `Dockerfile` (aka during docker image build). So as soon as you create your container (`docker compose up`), your shared volume on the host (which is empty) wipe out everything inside the container and delete your application in `/app` directory.

Comment: Yes, thank you both. Switching to a different directory worked like a charm for me. Could one of you post your comment as an answer? I will mark it as an answer solving the problem